# Prove that Language is Regular Using Closure Properties

Tags: automata, regular-language

Given: $L_1, L_2$ are regular languages. We define the language $L$.

$L = \{uw \mid \exists v \in \Sigma^*, uv \in L_1, vw \in L_2\}$.

I need to prove that $L$ is a regular language using only Closure Properties.

Answer (score 2):

Given a language $K$ of $A^*$ and a word $v\in A^*$, recall that
$$
  v^{-1}K = \{ u \in A^* \mid vu \in K\} \quad \text{and} \quad Kv^{-1} = \{ u \in A^* \mid uv \in K\}
$$
If $K$ is regular, then $v^{-1}K$ and $Kv^{-1}$ are regular. Furthermore, there are only finitely many sets of the form $v^{-1}K$ (respectively $Kv^{-1}$). Now your language can be written as
$$
  L = \bigcup_{v\in A^*} (L_1v^{-1}) (v^{-1}L_2)
$$
and hence $L$ is regular.

Comment: Why is "Furthermore, there are only finitely many sets of the form v−1Kv−1K" it true?

Comment: This is just an equivalent formulation of the [Myhill–Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill–Nerode_theorem).